# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option while creating PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Getting error as ORA-00922: missing or invalid option while creating PL/SQL procedure, here's the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE consession_calculate(item_ID IN NUMBER, CON_PRICE OUT NUMBER)
IS 
PRICE NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT ITEM_PRICE INTO PRICE FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_CODE=item_ID;
IF(PRICE<10) THEN
CON_PRICE:=PRICE;
ELSEIF(PRICE>=10 AND PRICE<=100) THEN
CON_PRICE:=(PRICE*10)*100;
ELSE 
CON_PRICE:=(PRICE*20)*100;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You're missing the PROCEDURE keyword in your "Create or Replace" e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE consession_calculate`. It may be worth checking out the documentation on Creating procedures in Oracle

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues:

- you're missing the `PROCEDURE` keyword
- `ELSEIF` should be `ELSE IF`
- you're missing and `END IF`.

The edited code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE consession_calculate(item_ID IN NUMBER, CON_PRICE OUT NUMBER) IS
    PRICE                                   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT ITEM_PRICE
      INTO PRICE
      FROM ITEM
     WHERE ITEM_CODE = item_ID;

    IF (PRICE < 10)
    THEN
        CON_PRICE    := PRICE;
    ELSE
        IF (    PRICE >= 10
            AND PRICE <= 100)
        THEN
            CON_PRICE    := (PRICE * 10) * 100;
        ELSE
            CON_PRICE    := (PRICE * 20) * 100;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Or, according to what **a_horse_with_no_name**  noticed you can only add the `PROCEDURE` and edit `ELSEIF` into `ELSIF`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE consession_calculate(item_ID IN NUMBER, CON_PRICE OUT NUMBER) IS
    PRICE                                   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT ITEM_PRICE
      INTO PRICE
      FROM ITEM
     WHERE ITEM_CODE = item_ID;

    IF (PRICE < 10)
    THEN
        CON_PRICE    := PRICE;
    ELSIF (    PRICE >= 10
           AND PRICE <= 100)
    THEN
        CON_PRICE    := (PRICE * 10) * 100;
    ELSE
        CON_PRICE    := (PRICE * 20) * 100;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Actually `elseif` should be `elsif`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right, I misunderstood the context and thought the OP wanted to use a new IF statement. Just edited, thanks